# Custom jQuery Validate rule to compare groups of input fields on forms

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've been searching the last few days for an answer and haven't found anything. I have a registration form that requires 4 team members - and each team member must provide a parent's email address.

Those email addresses need to be unique **UNLESS** the last name of the participant is the same.

For instance if team member #1's last name is Smith and the parent email is parent1@example.com - team members 2-4 could not use the same email address (i.e. parent1@example.com) **UNLESS** their last name was also Smith.

This is mainly to account for twins or other siblings that would be on the same team with the same parent. A quick Google search turned up a custom validation rule to make sure each input is unique. Link below.

http://www.anujgakhar.com/2010/05/24/jquery-validator-plugin-and-notequalto-rule-with-multiple-fields/

This works very well for making sure **ALL** of the parent emails must be unique but I don't know how to **ALSO** check the last name requirement. Some code below.

#### HTML Form. This is repeated for all 4 team members

```
<h3>Team Member #1 </h3>

<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" size="38" class="required" name="firstName_1" id="firstName_1">


<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" size="38" class="required team-last-name" name="lastName_1" id="lastName_1">


<label>Parent / Guardian Email Address</label>
<input type="text" size="38" class="required distinctemails" name="parentEmail_1" id="parentEmail_1">


<label>Confirm Parent / Guardian Email Address</label>
<input type="text" size="38" class="required" name="confirmParentEmail_1" id="confirmParentEmail_1">
```

#### Validation Code & Custom Rule

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqualToGroup", function(value, element, options) {
    // get all the elements passed here with the same class
    var elems = $(element).parents('form').find(options[0]);
    var valueToCompare = value;
    // count
    var matchesFound = 0;
    // loop each element and compare its value with the current value and increase the count every time we find one
    jQuery.each(elems, function(){
        thisVal = $(this).val();
        if(thisVal == valueToCompare){
            matchesFound++;
        }
    });
    // count should be either 0 or 1 max
    if(this.optional(element) || matchesFound <= 1) {
        elems.removeClass('error');
        return true;
    } else {
        elems.addClass('error');
    }
}, jQuery.format("Separate parent email addresses are required for each team member."));

$("#registration_form").validate({
    rules: {
        parentEmail_1: {
            email: true,
            notEqualToGroup: ['.distinctemails']
        }, 
        parentEmail_2: {
            email: true,
            notEqualToGroup: ['.distinctemails']
        }, 
        parentEmail_3: {
            email: true,
            notEqualToGroup: ['.distinctemails']
        }, 
        parentEmail_4: {
            email: true,
            notEqualToGroup: ['.distinctemails']
        }

    },
```

Again, the above works great for making sure each parent email field is unique - but I'm at a loss for how to compare those values to the parent's last name and **ONLY** allow the same email address where the parent last names match.

**EDIT**

Looks like there is some confusion about what my question is. I apologize if it's not clear. Basically it's this: How can I validate the form using jQuery Validate so that the parentEmail field is unique to all four team members **UNLESS** the parentLastName **AND** parentEmail match?

Comment: Is the last name a field on the form, or is there a pattern to the email addresses and you're parsing it for the last name?  If the last name is a field on the form, do you have a database linking email address of the parent to the last name?

Comment: Please go back and edit your question to be more clear and concise about these validation requirements.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I should've explain it a bit better. I've made some edits to the original question that hopefully clarifies it. Yes, all of the fields are on the form. The relevant fields I've added to the original post - notably first name, last name and parent email.

Comment: @Sparky, I've made some edits which hopefully make it a little clearer. To put it as concise as possible. I need to make sure a parent email cannot be used more than once unless the same last name is also used.

Comment: The problem here is that you apparently have not made any attempt at modifying this code for your special circumstances.  Have you attempted to modify the custom method function yet?  If so, show us what you've done and where/how you're stuck.  Otherwise, this seems straightforward... enclose the working parts within a conditional that determines whether or not the two last names match.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem! I have made attempts to modify it but I'm not entirely sure how it works - which is why I asked for help. I get that if there are more than one match found, it throws an error in the if statement. How exactly to check those matches to the last name is what I'm struggling with. Long story short, I simply don't know how to enclose the working parts within a condition that determines whether or not the two last names match. Any help there would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm working on this and when I put it into a jsFiddle, all validation failed.  You are missing a `;` after the custom method is declared.

Comment: You're right. What I pasted was just a partial copy/paste of the actual validation code - just so everyone could see the relevant parts. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not clean, nor would I consider it complete.  However, I think it's a good enough start for you to understand the logic and improve it from here.

1)  Grab the value of the Last Name field for the corresponding email field being validated...

```
var nameToCompare = $(element).prevAll('.team-last-name:first').val();
```

2)  Grab the value of the Last Name field for each email field within the loop...

```
thisLastName = $(this).prevAll('.team-last-name:first').val();
```

3) Then compare these within the loop *before* checking for duplicate email addresses...

```
if (thisLastName !== nameToCompare) {
    if (thisVal === valueToCompare) {
        matchesFound++;
    }
}
```

4) Tweak the number of matches found to `0` for passing validation, since now it's ignoring itself (*as it should have originally*)...

```
if (this.optional(element) || matchesFound === 0) { ....
```

5) Do **not** add/remove classes within the custom method.  The plugin already handles this automatically.  The **only** purpose of a custom method's function is to return `true` or `false` corresponding to pass or fail.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/1op3bzzz/**

**Issues**:

- timing:  you'll have to work on when this is triggered.  You could programmatically trigger validation on the entire form after a field is changed, however, then all messages will appear and validation will change from "lazy" to "eager".  The custom method is only triggered when interacting with the email fields.  You could also programmatically trigger it when interacting with the Last Name fields.  See [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid).
- blanks:  two blank last name field are considered as "matching" values.  With additional logic, you can filter these out unless they contain a value.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks so much! Seeing it laid out in your fiddle helped me understand what I was missing. This line: thisLastName = $(this).prevAll('.team-last-name:first').val(); was key. Seeing where that was within the loop helped it all make sense. I had already filtered out blank values counting as matches in the full version of my validation code. Thanks again.